# Polymer dom-repeat sub property changes child to host wiring

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer-1.0

I have a host element binding array of object to child element which has a `paper-input` to edit its properties. I don't see the value change on input reflected in the host `div` element. Even though on debug I can see that the host object has the latest edited `name`. What should I do to get this automatically wired ?

```
    <!-- Host element -->
<dom-module id="host-item">
    <template>
          <div>
             <div>[[selectedEmployee.name]]</div>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[employees]]" as="employee">
                    <item-edit item="[[employee]]"></item-edit>
                </template>
          </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
                is: 'host-item',
                properties: {                
                    selectedEmployee: {
                        type: Object 
                    },
                    employees: {
                      type: Array,
                      value = [ { name: 'Name 1'}, { name: 'Name 2'}, { name: 'Name 2'}]
                    }
                },
                ready: function() {
                  this.selectedEmployee = this.employees[0];
                }
            }); 
    </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- Child element -->
<dom-module id="item-edit">
    <template>
          <paper-input id="input" value="{{item.name}}" error-message="Invalid name!"></paper-input>            
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
                is: 'item-edit',
                properties: {                
                    item: {
                        type: Object
                    }
                }
            }); 
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{{employee}}` for [2 way binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding). `[[...]]` is for one way only.
Use [notify: true](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification) on property definition.

Child element should be defined before the parent.

Here is the working example [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bq2byDhGr4y9WrhwueIs?p=preview), and similar [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCx8gnPv4KL70FDu4tGD?p=preview)

```
<item-edit item="{{employee}}"></item-edit>
...
employee: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true,
                value: function () { return {name: 'Test' }; }
            }
```

Update:

Now "employees" data is in form of an array of objects. 
Check out this question for working with arrays: 
[Polymer, issue with binding array to paper slider value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966053/polymer-issue-with-binding-array-to-paper-slider-value)

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5ljGrqk8QG2pBXJaHSB?p=preview)

Docs: [Binding to array items](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding)

Comment: Please see edits to my question, I forgot to mention about dom-repeat. item-edit is within a dom-repeat.

Comment: Cant work out from the slider plunk where the actual fix is.

Comment: Check this, think it's fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/EnSyFcaFaeMUX8cElNCm?p=preview